# To output only a single .a static library in a project with cocoapods dependencies

Tags: ios, objective-c, dependencies, static-libraries, cocoapods

I am trying to build a static library that has different dependencies (AFNetworking for example) specified in a Podfile. And the project has a static library target, it will produce a static library(call libMyProject.a) for our customer use. I want all the cocoapods  dependencies to be included in the final static library (call libMyProject.a). but every cocoapods dependency will produce a .a file, how can I build them together, and only provide our customer one library for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you create the static library that includes other libraries, you're effectively by-passing Cocoapods mechanism of managing dependencies. Are you sure that this is what you want to do?

That said, given your static, all encompassing library, you will just need to put it in an accessible location, so that Cocoapods can download it, and include one pod declaration in your podfile.

In your podfile, you can also declare what version you wish to install from a given library. For instance, to specify version 4.0 of SomeLibrarySDK, you can say:

> pod 'SomeLibrarySDK', '~>4.0'

The effect is that only version 4.0 of SomeLibrary SDK will ever be downloaded and installed to your project, even after newer versions are published.

Comment: I don't want the 3rd library outside to be modified.

Comment: I see. You don't need to package third party libraries in your own, to prevent them to be modified. Instead, in your podfile, you can specify a version that you will use from a given library, and Cocoapods will not install the latest version.

Comment: I gave an example of this in the answer.

Comment: i think you didn't get it. if i used SomeLibrarySDK, then the user can get the source code and modify the code to get info in my static lib.

Comment: I see. So in that case, my first suggestion applies--you will be applying only one dependency through Cocoapods, which is your own, all-encompassing static library. You will need to use one single dependency declaration that corresponds to your library.